# Change Log for Contributions in Civicrm

Tags: logs

Is there a way that I have generate a change log in terms of what contribution is added, edited, deleted?
I understand that there is the detailed change log in civicrm, however seems like it doesn't include tracking of Contribution entity.

Could anyone assist me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

If you have enhanced logging enabled, your database will have tables like `log_civicrm_contribution` which you can examine, but there is no UI to display that.

Comment: The log table doesn't really show what was updated. Do you know a way that this could be done?

Answer (score 1):

When creating or editing contributions (such as changing it's status, type, amount etc.) a financial transaction will be created.

They could be considered a "change log for contributions" and are often used for accounting purposes (e.g. exporting them for your accounting software).

As many organisations don't need them, they are not prominently exposed in the UI. However, out of the box, there are some reports and export features for them, and of course you could use the search kit to display / use them in various ways.

If you would like to learn more about financial transactions and how to use them I would recommend the following sources:

https://civicrm.org/blog/erikhommel/to-have-or-not-to-have-financial-transactions
https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/financial/financialentities/
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/key-concepts-and-configurations/